# Chrome says "not secure" when a site is loading

Tags: google-chrome, security

I have noticed recently that when I click a link to go to a new site, or go to a site directly, while the site is loading, chrome shows the "circle i" button in the top left. When I click on it, it says "site not secure". However, once the site loads, chrome shows the lock button and says the site is secure. Is this unusual? I also notice it on my phone, usually with redirects. Does this mean that someone is using an MITM or other attack on me? Is my HTTPS being compromised, or am I just being paranoid?

Comment: it probably means that you asked for the HTTP version of the site, and the site implements redirect/rewrite rules to send you to the HTTPS version. see if you notice a change when you specify httpS:// in the url on first visit.

Comment: @FrankThomas i did that and it still says not secure until the page loads, and then it shows the normal lock and the site says it's secure.

Comment: well, the easiest way to be sure would probably be to install Fiddler, configure HTTPS support, and then you can watch the connection creation. HTTPS does take a few ticks to setup, but it should occur before any actual data on the connection is transmitted.

Comment: @nateh, Check this bro - https://security.stackexchange.com/q/179583